How can I improve this qu to get it reopened?
How secure is matrix multiplication when used as general purpose irreversible hashing?
I spent quite a bit of time making this question, coming up with a proof of concept and formatting it for readability. I think the context I gave may have pushed the question into realms of "review this entire encryption scheme". See Should we allow questions about amateur ciphers?
Really I'm interested only in a specific part at the heart of it, whether Matrix multiplication with a singular matrix is cryptographically secure as an irreversible hashing operation, and whether matrix multiplication is suitable for encryption. I think that falls into "in the context of X, does Y have the security property Z", or could be made to fit that structure but I'm too much of an amateur to know what to ask for. E.g. what properties to ask for it to have.
I have modified the question title and some wording to make it clear I care about the heart of it not the entire schema, but maybe more can be done to improve this question?

The question was closed on the generic reason that "reviewing full cryptographic designs are off-topic". And undoubtedly, much of it is a cryptographic design. Worse: beyond that, there's only a motivation for that design. But there's no amount of question beside the title!
So the first thing to change for a reopening is to state a question in the body of the question, with more detail than in the title.

When attempting to break the general guideline that asking about one's design is off-topic, the proposed design should be of high quality. And here, the design contains undesirable characteristics that are quickly discerned by many on crypto-SE, among which

That encryption is per linear algebra, thus quite suspect of being breakable with a few plaintext/salt/ciphertext triplets using the tools of linear algebra.
Ciphertext is much larger than plaintext (a lot with floating point, and by a factor like 4 if we consider the integer variation alluded to in the but-last paragraph of the question). This is undesirable for operational reasons, and turns out to help attacks.

Thus another recommendation is to refrain exposing in detail at least the encryption part of the currently proposed cryptosystem, because it breaks a standard rule, and actually discourages the audience.

The question is about matrices, and use matrix algebra. This assumes the values in the matrices belong to a field. The exposition in most of the question uses the field of reals, or rather a floating point approximation of that. As was promptly noted in comment, this is considered a poor idea in cryptography (because of 2 above, and numerical stability issues). I suggest that the question assumes matrix elements are in some small finite field, and that an illustration (if any) uses a simple field, e.g. arithmetic modulo a two-digits prime. It's also possible to use bytes (AES internally does just that) but the necessary field arithmetic can't be modulo 256.
Then, an acceptable question could be on the line of: Consider a transformation of secret P and random S into H per H = P∗S∗M, where M is a public singular matrix. Does that form a transformation of password P and salt S into H in a manner that satisfies some (stated) cryptographic criteria?
Pre-answer for that: a most central claim of the question is that password P can't be recovered from S, M, and H = P∗S∗M. An argument is made that since M is singular, we can't use P = H∗M-1*S-1. But that's a fallacy: that it can't be used a method to reach a goal is no proof that the goal can't be reached. And a more complete analysis shows that P can often be found making use of it's huge redundancy.
